# in a sub routine ... using return to get some elements of array

Tags: perl

I am trying to get some elements of array to return in the subroutine .it gives me only the last one dd 4 13

here is my csv

```
aa ,1 ,no ,ed ,8 
bb ,2 ,yes ,ed ,10
cc ,3 ,no ,ed ,12
dd ,4 ,yes ,ed ,13
```

here is my perl code

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

my $input_file  = $ARGV[0];
my @data =  read_data_from_csv($input_file);

sub read_data_from_csv
{
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my @d = ();

    open(FH, "<$fh") || die "Error: no open for $fh: $!";
  
    while (<FH>) {
    chomp;
    my @list =split(/,/);
    my ($aa) = $list[0];
    my ($bb) = $list[1];
    my ($cc) = $list[4];
    push (@d , ($aa, $bb, $cc));
}
close (FH);
    return @d
}

 print "@data\n";
```

```
cat test.csv 
aa ,1 ,no ,ed ,8 
bb ,2 ,yes ,ed ,10
cc ,3 ,no ,ed ,12
dd ,4 ,yes ,ed ,13
```

```
/pkg/qct/software/perl/5.20.0/bin/perl test.pl test.csv 
 dd  yes  13
```

Comment: I tried your code and it printed `aa  1  8  bb  2  10 cc  3  12 dd  4  13`.

Comment: You might be interested in [array slices](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perldata.html#Slices) to simplify your code: `push @d, @list[0,1,4];` or even `push @d, (split /,/)[0,1,4];`

Comment: As for only seeing a single row... I bet your CSV file has Windows style CRLF endings and you're running this on an OS with LF line endings. Try `open FH, "<:crlf", $fh` or running the file through `dos2unix` or `s/\r?\n//;` instead of `chomp`.

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Your code as posted works:

```perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
my @data       = read_data_from_csv($input_file);

sub read_data_from_csv {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my @d = ();

    #open(FH, "<$fh") || die "Error: no open for $fh: $!";

    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        my @list = split(/,/);
        my ($aa) = $list[0];
        my ($bb) = $list[1];
        my ($cc) = $list[4];
        push( @d, ( $aa, $bb, $cc ) );
    }
    close(FH);
    return @d;
}

print "@data\n";

 __DATA__
 aa ,1 ,no ,ed ,8 
 bb ,2 ,yes ,ed ,10
 cc ,3 ,no ,ed ,12
dd ,4 ,yes ,ed ,13
```

Output:

```
aa  1  8   bb  2  10  cc  3  12 dd  4  13
```

I would suggest you need to check your input file - if on unix, try `cat -v` which *might* show you you've got bad line endings.

An easy fix if you do have this problem (or to test it) is include:

```perl
s/[\r\n]//g;
```

More generally though I think there's a few errors in your code - that 'push' for example, probably isn't doing what you're thinking, because you're compressing your CSV into a flat array.

I'd also suggest using `Data::Dumper` to test outputs, because it's clearer what's happening:

```
$VAR1 = [
          ' aa ',
          '1 ',
          '8 ',
          ' bb ',
          '2 ',
          '10',
          ' cc ',
          '3 ',
          '12',
          'dd ',
          '4 ',
          '13'
        ];
```

As you can see, you've flattened your data, which I am *assuming* isn't what you want, based on what your write in `push`.

So you might want to consider using `[]` instead, because then you get:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            ' aa ',
            '1 ',
            '8 '
          ],
          [
            ' bb ',
            '2 ',
            '10'
          ],
          [
            ' cc ',
            '3 ',
            '12'
          ],
          [
            'dd ',
            '4 ',
            '13'
          ]
        ];
```

You can also direct assign array slices, rather than having a 1-1:

```
push ( @d, [ @list[0,1,4] ] );
```

Also as a final point - it's bad style to use single letter variables, and you should also `use warnings;`.

Giving you:

```perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Std;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $input_file = $ARGV[0];
my @data       = read_data_from_csv($input_file);

sub read_data_from_csv {
    my ($fh) = @_;
    my @d = ();

     ##NB Commented out so I can use inline data
    #open(FH, "<$fh") || die "Error: no open for $fh: $!";

    while (<DATA>) {
        chomp;
        s/[\r\n]//g;
        my @list = split(/,/);        
        push( @d, [ @list[0,1,4] ]);
    }
    ##close(FH);
    return @d;
}

print Dumper \@data;

 __DATA__
 aa ,1 ,no ,ed ,8 
 bb ,2 ,yes ,ed ,10
 cc ,3 ,no ,ed ,12
dd ,4 ,yes ,ed ,13
```

You might want to consider that instead of opening the file specified in `$ARGV[0]` this is precisely what the 'magic' file handle `<>` does. It opens file specified on command line and iterates them, but it *also* allows you to 'pipe' into the process on `STDIN`:

Making your program:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

## flattened array
my @data_A = map { s/[\r\n]//g; ( split(/,/) ) [0,1,4] } <>;     
## preserving structure
my @data_B = map { s/[\r\n]//g; [( split(/,/) ) [0,1,4]] } <>;    
print Dumper \@data_B;
```

I appreciate your code is probably a reduction of the core problem, but I'm just wanting to illustrate simplification options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS module.  Text::CSV_XS - comma-separated values manipulation routines. you can use functionality as per your requirement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my @rows;
my @column_numbers = (0,1,4);
my $csv_file = "tst.csv";
# check https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#binary
# check http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV_XS#auto_diag
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 });
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $csv_file or die "$csv_file: $!";
# $csv->getline_all ($fh); will return a reference to a list of getline ($fh) results.
#The map function of Perl provides a simple way to transform a list of values to another list of values.
@rows = map { [ @{ $_ }[@column_numbers] ] } @{ $csv->getline_all($fh) };
print Dumper(\@rows);
close $fh;
```

> Output

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'aa ',
            '1 ',
            '8 '
          ],
          [
            'bb ',
            '2 ',
            '10'
          ],
          [
            'cc ',
            '3 ',
            '12'
          ],
          [
            'dd ',
            '4 ',
            '13'
          ]
        ];
```

> Note : Please check solution provided by @ikegami [Unable to read multiple columns from a .csv using Text::CSV_XS in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420737/unable-to-read-multiple-columns-from-a-csv-using-textcsv-xs-in-perl)

> map: 1) https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html
> 2) https://perlmaven.com/transforming-a-perl-array-using-map